# How to get the path to a module in Centos 6.7 (or upgrade the gcc)?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, centos

I am trying to build from source and into a local library the package MIRA in Centos 6.7 using the ./configure make make install method. Given that the package requires gcc>=4.6 and my systems default is 4.4.7, I had to load a module using:

```
module load gcccuda/2.7.11
```

Which includes GCC/4.8.4 :

```
module list

Currently Loaded Modules:
1) GCC/4.8.4   2) CUDA/6.5.14-GCC-4.8.4   3) gcccuda/2.7.11
```

However, when I run the ./configure, the following error appears.

```
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

Another user solved the same problem by telling the program where to look for the library with the flag:

```
sudo ./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib
```

You can find his solution here: https://www.biostars.org/p/59182/ . Nevertheless, this solution is not exactly useful for me. I can't access the /usr/lib library in Centos (system in which I am relatively new) or find the path to the library GCC/4.8.4. I have also tried the generic --with-bost=yes to no avail.

Is there a way to inform the flag where the module is loaded so ./configure can proceed?

Some more information about MIRA installation: http://mira-assembler.sourceforge.net/docs/DefinitiveGuideToMIRA.html#chap_installation

Comment: What exactly do you think it is looking for when it says "Could not find a version of the library!"?  If you are not 100% certain, run the make command under `strace`, e.g. `strace -f ./configure 2>&1 | less` and look at the last few `open()` or other file-related commands it ran before it stopped.  Also, do you have `boost` available in your `module` system?  Maybe you should load a version from there.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I loaded module load Boost/1.61.0-foss-2016a, which included the CPP plus the Boost. However, the new error message  is: Ooops, we might encounter some problems in compilation/linking. Please give it a try and report success or failure. 
When I do make create the binaries, but the system spit an error